# I'm trying to create headers generated through NYT API that also takes you to the article

Tags: javascript, html, href

**I'm trying to create headers generated through NYT API that also takes you to the article**

Hello guys. Please be advised that I am a beginner :).

First of all thank you in advance!

I want to create headers that also take me to the article itself.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I've tried creating an inner HTML to create a nested tag, but it does not seem to work. I assume my approach to all this is entirely wrong. Any advice is welcome. Again, thank you for your patience and help.

```js
var url = 'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?q=picasso&api-key=1jmsdzQEx52HKDfIW8XglhrDcs0M1TqI'

function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    loadJSON(url, gotData);
}

function gotData(data) {
    var articles = data.response.docs;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var h1 =  createElement('h1', articles[i].headline.main);
    h1.class('headlines');
    h1.innerHTML= '<a href="#"></a>';
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName("headlines");
    a[i].setAttribute("href", articles[i].web_url);
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.left-section{
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.left-section:hover{
    font-weight: initial;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid brown;
    background-color: yellow;
}


.headlines{
    margin:10px;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    transition-property: transform;
}

.headlines:hover{
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: yellow;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    background-size: 300px 100px;
    cursor: pointer;  
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Write your comments here -->
        <section class ="main-page">
            <div class = "left-section">
                What's Good~
                <h3>
                    Yo,
                    <i>
                        Hello World!
                    </i>
                </h3>
        </section>
        <script src="script.js"></script>


    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```